# SUMIFS for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which I need to sum on column based on three criteria (employee name, payment option and dates). I currently have this formula

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C10,B2:B10,"Jason",D2:D10,"Cash")
```

But it works regardless of the dates. I wanted to only show the value for today.

This is the link to the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HshrfC05s_q9e5c78yReAUH8D2OBpcRBMTqJo8CPmwQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the third criteria:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C10,B2:B10,"Jason",D2:D10,"Cash",A2:A10,TODAY())
```

Comment: Awesome! You made it look so simple. You saved my day! I really apreciate it. Thank you so much, Excel Hero!